# capistrano deploy asking for USERNAME / PASSWORD on git ls-remote call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, github, capistrano

First time Capistrano user, I have set up the pieces from the best I can tell but when I run cap deploy, I get the following asking for my github username

```
Fri Dec 02$ cap deploy
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote https://github.com/uname/repo HEAD"
Username:
```

I'm assuming that this running locally on my OS X laptop. If I run `git ls-remote https://github.com/uname/repo`, I get prompted for a USERNAME. However, I can run git clone this repository fine, making me think that the local ssh keys are set up correctly. What am I missing here?

thx

edit #1 - top of deploy.rb

```
set :application, "test-rails"
set :repository,  "https://github.com/uname/app"

set :scm, :git
set :user, "deploy"
set :deploy_to, "/data/sites/site.com/apps/#{application}"
set :use_sudo, false
set :keep_releases, 5

role :web, "173.230.xxx.xxx"
```

Comment: Do you set your user name inside the `deploy.rb` like here: https://github.com/nesquena/cap-recipes/blob/master/examples/simple/deploy.rb#L16

Comment: I think so - I added the top of deploy.rb - the deploy user exists on server but not locally. Was under impression that 'locally' means essentially on host from where it is run.

Comment: also, I am able to clone the git repos with the `deploy` user on the remote host 172.230.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using an HTTPS URL.  This will ignore your SSH keys, and you'll have to do basic authentication over HTTPS.  You want your URL to instead be `ssh://git@github.com/uname/repo`.

(Cloning works because you can clone anonymously and don't need to authenticate.)

Comment: i just substituted in a git url

Answer (score 0):

perhaps it will help to others:
on target server make sure credentials for cached repo.
t cached my first NON password url and no matter how i update url in deploy.rb it was not updated on origin

in my case...

go to:
/srv/YOURREPONAME/shared/cached-copy

git remote show origin

make sure your origin has same URL as you trying to set in deploy.rb